# Show common elements in a list and how many times they appeared in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, function

I need to make a formula that, given two lists a and b, it returns the common elements in a and b. If the same element appears more than once in both, let's say xa times in a and xb times in b, then x should appear min(xa,xb) times in the results. If it's possible, don't use "import" in the code, please.

For example:
(Supposing my function is called common(a,b))

`common([1,3,3,3],[1,3,3,3,3,4])
=>  [1,3,3,3]`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show the community what you have done so far. Stackoverflow is not the place that can help you doing your homework.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: No, it's part of a challenge given to me by my friend that i haven't been able to complete so far.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is sort the two list first and compare the first element one by one. The code is like this:

```
def common(a, b):
    sorted_a, sorted_b = sorted(a), sorted(b)

    numa, numb = len(a), len(b)
    rv = []
    i, j = 0, 0

    while i < numa and j < numb:
        if sorted_a[i] == sorted_b[j]:
            rv.append(sorted_a[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif sorted_a[i] < sorted_b[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
    return rv
```

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to resolve this problem:

1. Find out those elements should be in the final list, which is the `intersection` of two lists
2. For each element found in step #1, find out how many times it should be in final list
3. Generate final list based on the info found by previous two steps

And then translate these 3 steps to three lines of code:

```
def common(l1, l2):
    intersection = [e for e in l1 if e in l2] 
    elemnts_counters = {e: min(l1.count(e), l2.count(e)) for e in intersection} 
    return sum([[e] * c for e, c in elemnts_counters.items()], [])
```

Then

```
print common([1,3,3,3], [1,3,3,3,3,4])
```

will give you:

> [1, 3, 3, 3]

Answer (score 0):

```
def common(lista=None,listb=None):
    result_list=list()
    inter_dict=dict()
    lista_count=dict()
    listb_count=dict()
    for i in lista:
        lista_count[i]=lista_count.get(i,0)+1 #convert lista to dict with frequency
    for i in listb:    
        listb_count[i]=lista_count.get(i,0)+1 #convert listb to dict with frequency
    for key in set(lista_count).intersection(set(listb_count)):
        inter_dict[key]=min(lista_count[key],listb_count[key]) # get intersection of two dicts
    for k,v in inter_dict.items():
        result_list.extend([k]*v) #extend to the output list  
    return result_list
```

The output will give you when invoke the function common([1,3,3,3],[1,3,3,3,3,4]):

**[1, 3, 3, 3]**

Answer (score 0):

```
def common(l1,l2):

  totalElements = l1 + l2 
  resultList = []
  for num in totalElements:
    if num in l1 and num in l2:
      resultList.append(num)
      l1.remove(num)
      l2.remove(num)

  return resultList  

l1 = [1,3,3,3,5]
l2 = [1,3,3,3,5,3,4]
result = common(l1 , l2)
print(result)
```

[1, 3, 3, 3, 5]